# What's the differences between boisterous and tumultuous?

Tags: difference

What's the differences between boisterous and tumultuous? Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Boisterous* can be used of a person who is lively and noisy in a cheerful way. A *tumult* is a noisy, confused disturbance, usually among a group of people, caused by anger or fear. Both adjectives can be used to describe wild, stormy weather.